# What is defined behavior of std::upper_bound on an empty end range?

Tags: c++, range, std, stl-algorithm

I'm trying to understand in C++ whether the standard allows as valid a call to `std::upper_bound` with a range that is the `end()` of a container to its `end()`?

In other words, is the empty range [`end()`, `end()`) a valid range?  Is `end()` reachable from itself?  Does the answer remain the same in C++98 as it does in C++11?

Comment: if empty range is not allowed then that's a defect. so this question involves (1) looking for relevant language, and if not found, (2) looking for defect reports. have you tried that yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[first, last)
```

Standard says that `[first, last)` is not a valid range if *first is behind the last* in the range. That makes `[cont.end(), cont.end()]` a valid range. However, algorithms are no-op for these ranges.
For e.g:-

```
std::reverse(cont.end(), cont.end());
```

is just a no-op rather than undefined behavior.